# Issue On Getting Sum of a Table Column Using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you please take a look at this demo and let me know why I am not getting the sum of the .`app` cells?

```js
var total = 0;
$(".app").each(function() {
  total += parseInt($(this).val());
});

$("#total").html(total);
```

```css
#total {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td class="app">50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td class="app">94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td class="app">94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br />
<div id="total"></div>
```

Comment: White text on a white background isn't a good idea :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `parseInt($(this).val());` to `parseInt($(this).html());` as the td cells do not have any value attribute and change the `color` property for total to `#000`(black), as the output will not be visible.

```js
var total = 0;
$(".app").each(function() {
  total += parseInt($(this).html());
});

$("#total").html(total);
```

```css
#total {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 15px;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td class="app">50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td class="app">94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td class="app">94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br />
<div id="total"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `html()`:

```
var total = 0;
$(".app").each(function() {
    total += parseInt($(this).html());
});

$("#total").html(total);
```

The `val()` method is used to get value from form elements like inputs and selects. [Docs](http://api.jquery.com/val/)